# Trying to implement AJAX into my admin pages. Am I improperly enqueue and localizing my scripts?

Tags: custom-field, jquery, metabox, ajax

I'm trying to implement AJAX into my post edit form in order to hook a custom wp function into a link click.  So far I've been able to register my custom js file into my admin header.  However when testing my link click nothing is happening unless I do an alert() in my jQuery.

Here is my code for the href link I want to hook into my custom function:

```
<a href="#" id="delete-' . $field['id'] . '" class="delete_pdf" title="Delete this PDF." >Delete</a>
```

Here's my code in my functions.php for registering, enqueue, and localizing scripts, as well as my custom function (still work in progress):

```
//Add AJAX functionality to post.php to delete files
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts');
add_action('wp_ajax_delete_meta', 'delete_pdf_and_metadata');

//Add my custom JS to the header of admin
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts($hook) {
    global $current_screen;

    if ( 'post.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_register_script('my-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom/my-scripts.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('my-scripts');
    wp_localize_script('my-scripts', 'wp_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}

function delete_pdf_and_metadata() {

    global $post;

    $the_id = intval($_POST['the_id'] );
    //echo $the_id . '<br />';  //debugging
    //echo $key . '<br />';  //debugging
    wp_die($the_id);   //debuggin

    //delete_post_meta( $post->ID, $key );  //TODO
}
```

Here's my jQuery in my `my-scripts.js` file I've successfully registered:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.delete_pdf').each(function(i,e) { //grab the class delete-pdf
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/delete-/, '');
        $(this).click(function(){
            //alert('Clicked! '+ $(this).attr('id'));  //THIS WORKS WHEN CLICKED
            $.post(wp_ajax.ajaxurl, { action: 'delete_meta', the_id: id }, function(data){
                });
        });
    });

    function replace_pdf_with_file_upload(){
        //TODO write to replace PDF link with File Upload

    }
});
```

In my jQuery, if I do an alert() when clicking the link it works fine.  However when I try to test my custom function `delete_pdf_and_metadata()` by simply doing a `wp_die()`, I get absolutely nothing.  Not even exceptions in firebug where I'm debugging javascript.

I think it has to do with the way I localized the scripts, but I'm not sure.  this is my first dive into using AJAX with WordPress.

Am I missing something?

Comment: On the admin side, `ajaxurl` is already available as a global javascript variable, so you don't actually need that localizing part.
What is the response of the ajax call if you enable debugging? (DEBUG=TRUE in config file)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, when I comment out this line:

`wp_localize_script('my-scripts', 'wp_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));` 

And click my link to call my ajax I get the error 
"wp_ajax is undefined" in my javascript error console.

Also enabling debugging doesn't give me any info on the ajax call...

Comment: in your JS file replace `wp_ajax.ajaxurl` with `ajaxurl`.

Comment: Did that, still nothing. Can't even get a simple alert() inside my function to fire. it's not firing the function and I'm not sure why. No errors in javascript console though...

Comment: Dunno if I'm onto something but... Since we're passing 'wp_ajax' into 'wp_localize_script' I tried doing this in my JS file:  `alert(wp_ajax.alert);`.  It alerts 'UNDEFINED'.  Am I passing the correct values into my localize script function?

Comment: Check the Network/XHR tab in Firebug to debug ajax requests. You can check if the ajax call is made and what is the response form the back-end.

Comment: Ok did that, under POST I see
action: delete_meta
the_id: aps_pdf1  //this is correct

And under RESPONSE i'm getting 0

Comment: It actually looks like it is calling the function delete_pdf_and_metadata(), how can I test for sure? I tried an alert() in my function but it errors out in firebug saying: Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  alert() in mytheme/functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments above, you are just passing a wrong id or you need to modify delete_pdf_and_metadata function. intval('aps_pdf1') is 0, and that's why your response is 0!

Comment: Ok I'll work on that! What should it return if it worked?  THANK YOU !